# Return value from Data Extension only if data exists

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

Trying to figure out a way to return a value from a Field in a data extension only if the field is non-blank.

I want to send an email with a personalized greeting ("Hey, *First Name*! Here's this week's content") but the issue I'm running in to is that not everyone has provided their first name.

I'm wondering if there's a way to run a check that says

If first name is blank then return "Here's this week's content"
else
Return "Hey, First Name, Here's this week's content".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common case for AMPscript, and there are various ways to accomplish this.  I prefer this method, whereby all the copy and logic lives in the AMPscript block, with just the result being shown in the HTML.

```
<html>
<head>
    %%[
    SET @firstname = AttributeValue("FirstName")
    SET @SalutationA = Concat("Hey, ",@firstname," Here's this week's content")! 
    SET @SalutationB = "Here's this week's content"

    IF @firstname == "" THEN
      SET @text = @SalutationB 
    ELSE
      SET @text = @SalutationA
    ENDIF

    ]%%

</head>
<body>
  <p>%%=v(@text)=%%</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This solutions seems quite elegant. However, when I tried to implement I got the error:

The script condition contains an invalid comparison operator.
 Condition: @firstname = ""

Is there another way I should be looking at a cell containing a null value?

Comment: it needs to be two equal signs. "=="

Comment: Also can use IF EMPTY([at]firstname) and I would change the first variable to be SET [at]firstname = AttributeValue("FirstName") as this will better handle NULL values and more.(Plus it will make @AdamSpriggs happy and we all want that!) [at] used in place of 'commercial at' sign as comment will only let me use one.

Comment: This all makes sense to me, but for some reason SalutationA is returning "Hey, @firstname! Here's this week's content" rather than filling in firstname with the actual name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ampscript if statement something like:

```
%%[ If Not Empty @firstname Then ]%% 
show first name here
%%[ Else ]%%
show backup if empty
%%[ Endif ]%%
```